# How do I solve this matrices problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Well,I need to find for which values of the parameter a the the rank of the matrices is :-

1. rank=1
2. rank=2
3. rank=3
4. rank=4

note that the parameter a is a complex number.
I tried to solve it but all the times I just find values for a that fits rank=3.

Comment: Do you know Gauss elimination method to find rank of a matrix?

Comment: No.What does it state?

Comment: [Gauss elimination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html) is the process of [row-reducing](http://www.mathportal.org/algebra/solving-system-of-linear-equations/row-reduction-method.php) a matrix. This is among the first things one learns when studying linear algebra and a need-to-know technique. After row-reducing the matrix its all a matter of counting to get the answer ([see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Computing_the_rank_of_a_matrix)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to solve it for you, but here is a possibility to find values, where the rank is equal to $4$. This happens if and only if the determinant is nonzero, i.e., iff
$$
a(a-1)(a+2)(a^2+a+1)\neq 0.
$$
So, did you try an integer $a$ different from $0,1,-2$ ?

Comment: the parameter a is a complex number

Comment: This is true, but $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$, i.e., integers are also complex numbers, and you could try, say, $a=3$.